# Error with Everyplay Sharing To Facebook / facebook login in for unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, everyplay

mailed everyplay about this as well as having searched numerous facebook issues that deal with the same problem .

As of now whenever or user finishes a game session and pulls up the sharing modal everything for the most part is fine . sharing to youtube twitter , and e-mail works flawlessly but sharing to facebook is throwing an error and I would love to know if anyone else has encountered or fixed this issue .

The error in question states : **" Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the Apps "** domains.

I feel like this must be an issue on the facebook side but I am unsure of what app domains or Canvas URL to use that will bring up the Everyplay login .

I have tried triple checking the documentation to see if there is any info we needed to include on our facebook side of things but so far I've got nothing . I thought possibly the issue might be our use of the facebook SDK in conjunction with Everyplay but I'm unsure . Any and all help would be appreciated as I have no idea where this error comes form .

Comment: Do you happen to have the Facebook SDK bundled with your application (or the Facebook plugin for Unity), and is this iOS or Android build you are testing with?

Comment: yes we do have the facebook SDK bundled with our application Tuomas and  we are testing on iOS but our app will be available for both OS's ultimately

Comment: Can you drop me an email to support@everyplay.com your game name and client_id and I'll dig up some info if I can. I'll post the solution here when we figure it out for others to see, but it might be easier to switch to email for now.

Comment: Hey Tuomas from what i understand the issue was Everyplay side and they wee able to help me resolve it , thanks!!!

Comment: Can you share the answer please?